# How to inspect std::string in GDB with no source code?

Tags: c++, stl, gdb, std

I'm trying to debug a program that has no source code available, and I need to look at what it has stored in a std::string. I've been Googling and looking on here, and I've found some information about outputting STL containers, but all of it refers to variables, with no source or debug information all I have is a memory offset of the class data. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Every `std::string` implementation has a pointer to the raw characters in it somewhere. For `g++ 4.x`, that pointer is at offset `0` into the string.

If you know that the string resides at e.g. `0x7fffffffda88`, then

```
print *(char**)0x7fffffffda88
```

is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. One thing I'd like to know is how I'd figure something like that out myself. i.e. given the source code for class 'X' how would I figure out the position of fields within that class? The only way I can think of at the moment is to compile my own test application and examine the pointers I'm given (with offsetof, etc).

Comment: The fastest way to figure out the offset is in fact to compile a trivial test program using the given class in debug mode, and examine the offsets and class layout in GDB. That's exactly what I've done to answer your question ;-)

Comment: As an aside, if SSO is used like in clang's libc++, there is no such pointer for small strings. ;-)

Comment: This is so helpful. I am trying to look into a std::string variable when debugging a core dump. However, command like "p s.size()" or "p s.c_str()" do not work in this case (gdb will annoyingly keep saying "You can't do that without a process to debug" ). The method posted here gives a workaround.

Answer (score 31):

Perhaps the easiest option is to use the `c_str` method, as in:

```
print myStr.c_str()
```

Comment: This does not work on GDB 9.1-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS