# GDB: Printing value of a function argument in a memory location

Tags: c++, gdb, valgrind

I'm using Valgrind and GDB to debug a memory leak. I've the following call trace that shows where the memory leak occurs:

```
(gdb)  monitor block_list 10104
==961== 153 (18 direct, 135 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10,104 of 10,317
==961==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==961==    by 0x678199: create_node(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, document*) (a.cpp:436)
==961==    by 0x67933A: insert(art_node*, art_node**, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, document*, unsigned int, int, int*) (a.cpp:704)
==961==    by 0x68327B: Program::add(std::string const&) (program.cpp:84)
==961==    by 0x7220BF: main (main.cpp:52)
```

I want to print the value of the string argument that's passed to `Program::add` at:

```
==961==    by 0x68327B: Program::add(std::string const&) (program.cpp:84)
```

How do I do that in GDB?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line inside the function, run the program and wait for it to hit the breakpoint, then `print <variable name>` should do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inspect std::string in GDB with no source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776961/how-to-inspect-stdstring-in-gdb-with-no-source-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow step by step [Valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver):

> If you want to debug a program with GDB when using the Memcheck tool,
>   start Valgrind like this:
>
> ```
> valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 prog
> ```
>
> In another shell, start GDB:
>
> ```
> gdb prog
> ```
>
> Then give the following command to GDB:
>
> ```
> (gdb) target remote | vgdb
> ```

Now you can go to frame `Program::add(std::string const&)` in gdb and print the value of argument.