# gdb <error reading variable> for any string object

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, mingw

Lets take this very simple program here for example:

```
// test.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "Hello";
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

now I compile this code with g++ compiler:

```
g++ -g test.cpp -o test.exe
```

now I am trying to debug this with gdb:

```
gdb test.exe
```

after I set breakpoint on main and then reach the line `return 0`, I try to see what is in the string str. But I cannot print it in the console. It says `<error reading variable>`. Not only in gdb console, even Visual Studio Code UI using gdb gives the same output.

Here is a screenshot of my console:
[image]

I have searched for this everywhere and the only relevant question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776961/how-to-inspect-stdstring-in-gdb-with-no-source-code), which did not work.
I also found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6790) post on github VS Code repo issues. The fix suggested there might work I am not sure, I cannot find the setting that he suggested on my Windows 11 machine.

How do I read the value in the string in debug mode?

**Edit**
After @ssbssa suggested me to update my gcc, I used MSYS2 to get the latest gcc, g++, and gdb versions. Now I have gdb 12.1. Now it is not showing the old error anymore but now it says "Converting character sets: Invalid argument". Still struggling to get it to work.

[image]

Comment: @ChandrachurMukherjee [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778040/14414944) didn't work?

Comment: no, screenshot shows i tried it. same result.

Comment: Since your gdb version is from 2013, I suggest you update.

Comment: What is your GCC version? Do you build 64 bit executable?

Comment: gcc version was previously 7.6.1 and I updated it to the latest version after @ssbssa suggested so. Now I am having a different problem. I am going to edit my question to update my current problem. Yes I am running 64 bit g++ on 64 bit machine, so I think the executable will also be 64bit.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67991808/1983398), the character set problem is related to the reading variable problem. Maybe try `set charset UTF-8` as the answer states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run your program with gdb like so:

```
gdb test.exe
```

Now inside the command line interface run the command:

```
set charset UTF-8
```

This should temporarily fix your problem. The only inconvenience might be that you need to run this line every time you debug on your command prompt with GDB.

I noticed that you are also using Visual Studio Code. You can install C++ extensions for VS Code and there you can add the command `set charset UTF-8` in the launch.json setupCommands array as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991808/vscode-debugger-having-issues-with-character-encoding). This way you can debug your application faster.